# Swift: Difference between closure, completion handler and function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, function, closures

Can anyone let me know what are advantages of closures over functions?
When should we use closures and functions with example ?

Answer (score 2):

Well,

first of, **Closures are Functions, Functions are Closures** only one has a name, the other doesn't.
Meaning, when you have a func, you can call it whenever you want from wherever it is visible: myfunc() that's it.
Closure are the same, only they have no name, so to be call they have to be stored in variable (one you declare, or as a parameter to a method)

Note that function that take closure as parameters also accept function name...

so you should see things like this : code used several time in my code : => go function... one time execution block I'd give to a method from another guy's api => closure.

Comment: Functions are indeed a special case of closures, but closures are not functions, per se (functions describe a smaller subset of structures contained in the set covered by closures).

Comment: I agree, I might have take a rough shortcut here :)